# javascript jquery veriification won't catch verification sent

Tags: javascript, jquery

good day i'm having a problem with my code it won't continue if fields met the if statements having a problem giving the data because i think the javascript catches the verification but won't continue on and gives me the  Sorry, error occured this time sending your message. that's my catcher if any error happends when you upload .

[image]

here's my javascript code

http://pastebin.com/6QV3syxL

and here's my verification boxes

http://pastebin.com/31VNpbkk

[image]

. the verification process works but the part where the script give the information and the javascript catches it it fails and won't continue to give the data to the sql statement

Comment: -2 can you point why you gave me -2?

Comment: I didn't downvote you; I'm sure those who did should comment very soon. I'm guessing it's because your question wasn't formatted enough to make much sense.

Comment: when i gave the complete data of the fields it still gives me sorry error occured so i'm having a problem with my javascript link it in pastebin to properly align it -_-. and gave me -2

Comment: No idea about the -2 votes as you provide a lot of detail, but looking at your code you really need to consider data-driving the validation (e.g. from data- attributes on the fields). Hard-coding validation like that is a maintenance nightmare and goes against every standard validation system I have seen.

Comment: i did put my question again at the bottom part

Comment: I would suggest putting it all into a JSFiddle so that wanna-vote coders can play with it :)

Comment: you should reduce your code to what is relevant to reproduce issue, i guess nobody wants to read 800 lines of code. my 2 cents.

Comment: oh god -3 :D i put the complete details and got -3 whattt.didn't even give explanations . sorry mr @hitech Magic still a beginner terms on php and javascript

Comment: :D sorry because a part of that code causes the malfunction of the code but it the validation part is redundant so i decided to put it. @Pascamel

Comment: Sorry to see you catch so much flak so quickly. That's a fact of life on this website I'm afraid. I would suggest carefully rewording your explanation as it does not read very well. Grammar is important.

Comment: @Ermel i get you but try to reduce your code first. This could help you to find the error by yourself too. i'm working on a one million lines of code project at my work, should i copy one million of lines of code here if I get an error I can't resolve? ;) Just trying to explain you why you got downvoted.

Comment: yeah next time i'll properly arrange my codes sorry having really messy grammar . i'm not quite well with grammar so maybe the ones who read this didn't really understood my question as you said my explanation is really messy thanks for the advice . @HiTechMagic

Comment: @Pascamel yeah my bad trying to reduce it and give one line of column only if it's successful my bad. :D but got an important lesson don't declare variable repeatedly haha

Comment: +1 for learning something positive from this "negative" experience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your validation code blocks you redefine your `error` variable.

```
if(!lname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/))
{
     var error = true;
     $('#lname_error').fadeIn(500);
}
else
{
     $('#lname_error').fadeOut(500);
}
```

Try removing the `var` so the same variable is used througout the code and not new variables each time.

```
if(!lname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/))
{
     error = true;
     $('#lname_error').fadeIn(500);
}
else
{
     $('#lname_error').fadeOut(500);
}

...

if(error == false){
     ...
}
```

Comment: i'll try it because i think that's right because i declare the var error repeatedly and gives the error thanks i'll try this

Comment: having an error on the last part but it's saving on our database :D thanks for patiently reading our code . i'll try to fix my last error gonna get back here if still nothing if you don't mind thanks for answering @bun